# Get final position of Moving object along the collision surface using ProjectOnPlane

Tags: unity

I have a problem to get the final position of moving object along the collision surface..
as you can see in picture <1>
i want to get moveAmount.

so i get sameLengthWithDiffProjected on picture <2>
but it's not the result what i expected.

what is my mistake?
how can i get the final position?
thanks in advance.

[image]

```
    horRayLength = horMoveAmount.magnitude/* + skinWidth*/;
    isHit = Physics.CapsuleCast(capsuleTop, capsuleBottom, capsuleCollider.radius, horMoveAmount.normalized, out raycastHit, horRayLength, horCollisionMask);
    if (isHit)
    {
        if (raycastHit.distance != 0)
        {
            var diff = horMoveAmount - raycastHit.point;
            var projected = Vector3.ProjectOnPlane(diff, raycastHit.normal);
            var sameLengthWithDiffProjected = projected.normalized * (diff.magnitude);
            var horMinusDiff = horMoveAmount - diff;
            moveAmount.x = horMinusDiff.x + sameLengthWithDiffProjected.x;
            moveAmount.z = horMinusDiff.z + sameLengthWithDiffProjected.z;
        }
    }
```

Comment: and thanks to @DMGregory I saw your solution [link](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/136595/39518) but i'm not sure what it means...

Comment: Can you clarify how the result in diagram 2 differs from what you expected?

Answer (score 0):

Your calculation of the remaining move vector looks slightly wrong, you are using the absolute position of the collision, where you want to be using the amount moved so far. Instead you should include the current position of the object in your calculation:

```
var movedToFar = raycastHit.point - transform.position;
var diff = horMoveAmount - movedToFar;
```

Once you have this, you can get your final point by adding the projected diff to your collision point, e.g:

```
var finalPoint = raycastHit.point + sameLengthWithDiffProjected;
```

Additionally you may fine the [Debug.DrawRay](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Debug.DrawRay.html)/DrawLine methods quite useful for visualising what is going on.

Comment: aha. i got your point. but it does not work.. maybe my calculation is not correct...

Comment: Updated to calculate the final point, it looks like your are trying to adjust the movement amount instead in your code. You might find that easier to do from your initial and final points. If that still doesn't work, you might find using Debug.DrawRay/DrawLine to visualise the collisionNormal and moves etc to be helpful.